# Career Change in to Testing

Tags: career-development

I've around 10+ years of experience in Banking operations including  reconciliations, sales, customer services, asset management, and financial transaction QA.  Coming to academics I've done my PG in commerce (costing, auditing, banking, and statistics) also a diploma in project management, ISTQB foundation, Prince 2 foundation and ITIL foundation.

Can any one advise me if the testing role is ideal for me and how to start with it.

Answer (score 7):

> Can any one advice me the testing role is ideal for me and how to
>   start with please.

You might wish to inquire with your current company if there is a QA position available.

Internal transfers are a great way to launch a new career.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above answer. Internal transfers are the best way to go. However, if you do not find any opportunity, try to find a place which looks for a manual tester to test the applications that deal with your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

As said above, Internal transfer are best way to start your career. If so you do not find any opportunity, then with **free beta testing** opportunity available for lots of Mobile application, build your reputation in testing community. Later you can start freelancing showing some testing portfolio/experience and get projects.

Also try to learn functional automation and non-functional testing in spare time.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have a lot of financial domain knowledge which will be useful for testing financial apps.  You can "try on" testing as a job though some of the crowd-sourced testing services.  These services, like utest.com or mob4hire.com will setup paid testing gigs (often paid for the bug submitted).

Weekend testing (http://weekendtesting.com/) is another way to try the role. They organize test cycles, share results, and support each-other by organizing test cycles during, well, the weekend.

These are a couple of ways to build experience, and see if you like testing.