# Want to be Software Tester? From where to start?

Tags: career-development

I have done C/C++ in 2007. In between 2008 to 2015 I was doing business. Now I want to study again. I want to be Software Tester (Master Level). Can anybody help me and let me know how & from where to Start. Is their any Prerequisite Course required for the same?

Comment: Similar question is asked every week - please search first

Comment: see http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9313/career-change-in-to-testing?rq=1

Comment: You should get together with the person who wrote this question: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/17375/want-to-start-learning-software-testing

Answer (score 1):

**First,** you will need to learn basics of software Testing

There are plenty of resources available online teaching Software testing. You can start from following course. https://www.udemy.com/qa-software-testing-training-course/

You can also look for blogs/tutorials teaching basics of software testing.

**Secondly,** If you have previous development experience and have personal interest towards scripting. Then you can also go on to become an automation tester (writing automation scripts with java).

Choosing between developer and QA/Automation is your personal choice. It will depend on your personal interest towards programming and your skills level in programming.

Comment: Good answer. I just want to clarify that automation testers does not only write automation scripts (and in particular not in Java), see for example: http://www.satisfice.com/presentations/agileauto.pdf

Comment: completely agree that automation is not limited to script writing and java. I just mentioned these as he seemed to be a beginner with incline towards java.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm a tester so I'm little biased. I would follow a tester path.

It offers you many different specializations with different areas to grow. [James Back describes](http://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/958) many types of testers you can become:

> - Automated? Manual? There is no such thing as manual or automated testing. It’s all just testing. Testing is often supported by tools
>     that attempt to simulate user interaction with the system. This is
>     what people call “test automation” even though it is only automating a
>     crude approximation of one aspect of testing. If you have the ambition
>     to be a one-man test team, it is extremely valuable to learn how to
>     make your own tools.
> - Exploratory? Scripted? There is no such thing as an exploratory or scripted tester. All good testing is exploratory to some degree and
>     scripted to some degree.
> - Tester. This is a testing generalist who can contribute to any test team. Sometimes called a QA analyst, QA engineer, or test engineer. I
>     prefer the simplicity of “tester.”
> - Omega Tester. The omega tester (which I sometimes call a test jumper, after the analogy of a paratrooper) is one who can do
>     anything. An omega tester is equipped to be the only tester in a
>     project team, if necessary. Omega testers can lead testing, or work
>     with a team of other testers. I am an omega tester. I aspire to be a
>     good one.
> - Performance Tester. The performance tester understands the mathematics and dynamics of the performance of large-scale systems.
>     They use tools that create high loads and measure the performance
>     envelope of systems as they scale up.  Performance testers often don’t
>     think of themselves as testers.
> - Usability Tester. The usability tester is a bit mythical. I have met only two dedicated usability testers in my entire career, but I have
>     seen more of them from a distance. A usability tester specializes in
>     studying how users feel about using and learning a product.
> - Security Tester. Security testers also often don’t think of themselves as testers. Security is an exciting, specialized form of
>     testing that requires the mastery of a great many facts about a great
>     many technologies.
> - Testing Toolsmith. A testing toolsmith is a programmer dedicated to writing and maintaining tools that help testers. This is what a lot of
>     people would call an “automated tester” but you better not use that
>     term around me.
> - “SDET” Software Development Engineer in Test. This
>     means a full on programmer who does testing using his programming
>     skills.